# SQL - How to select recent record after a specific status

Tags: sql

Product table query

```
Select Product, Quantity, Status, Txn_date  from ProductTransaction
```

[Table]

[image: 1]

**Required Output** Fetch only one immediate 'Received' status record after the recent status 'Ship' for each product

[image: 2]

I tried so far..but **it's wrong**

```
Select p.Product, p.Quantity, p.Status, p.Txn_date 
from ProductTransaction p
inner join 
(
      Select  Product, Status,  max(Txn_date) as LatestDate
    from ProductTransaction 
    where status='Ship'
    Group by Product,Status
) SubMax 
on p.Txn_date > SubMax.LatestDate
and p.Product = SubMax.Product 
and p.Status='Recieved'
```

**wrong result** - **Don't** need all 'Received' status. Only need to fetch older txn_date record for each product

[image: 3]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH ProductTransaction (Product, Quantity, Status, Txn_date) AS
(
VALUES
  ('P504', 50, 'Received',     '2021-03-18'::DATE)
, ('P504', 50, 'Transit',      '2021-03-17'::DATE)  
, ('P504', 25, 'Received',     '2021-03-16'::DATE)
, ('P504', 58, 'ShipToStore',  '2021-03-15'::DATE)
, ('P504', 32, 'Ship',         '2021-03-14'::DATE)
, ('P504', 20, 'Active',       '2021-03-12'::DATE)
, ('P504', 30, 'Acknowledged', '2021-03-12'::DATE)
, ('P504', 20, 'Ship',         '2021-03-10'::DATE)
, ('P510', 25, 'Ship',         '2021-03-15'::DATE)
, ('P510', 35, 'Acknowledged', '2021-03-12'::DATE)
, ('P510', 25, 'Received',     '2021-03-12'::DATE)
, ('P510', 25, 'Ship',         '2021-03-10'::DATE)
)
*/
SELECT Product, Quantity, Status, Txn_date
FROM
(
SELECT 
  P.*
, LAG (STATUS) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY TXN_DATE) STATUS_PREV
FROM ProductTransaction P
WHERE STATUS IN ('Received', 'Ship')
)
WHERE STATUS = 'Received' AND STATUS_PREV = 'Ship';
```

This query returns the result needed.

Comment: It's returning empty table.

When I execute Inner query: it's return all ship status records. executed whole query, returns empty table

** inner query result:**
`**P504** 20 Ship 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000 NULL
**P504** 32 Ship 2021-03-14 00:00:00.000 Ship
**P510** 25 Ship 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000 NULL`

Comment: Check this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=5da8da2504d485f71e027f5724a534f7) link.

Comment: It's so close to the logic but check this scenario. how to get min data? check this [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b8358a1f34c31e0e77f4961edcbb902e)

Comment: I think this will work [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=1145c6eb2e66d1532be066539c732ce9)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions

```
select pt.*
from (select pt.*,
             max(case when status = 'Shipped' then txn_date end) over (partition by product) as max_shipped_date
      from ProductTransaction pt
     ) pt
where status = 'Received' and txn_date > max_shipped_date
```

Comment: Please check the required output. need only one record for each product (should be older txn_date). Above query result.  `P504 25 Recieved 2021-03-16 2021-03-14,  P504 50 Recieved 2021-03-18 2021-03-14, P510 25 Recieved 2021-03-12 2021-03-10`

Answer (score 0):

I think, Meanwhile I have to go with nested sub queries. Please let me know if we can tune up this query.

`select pt2.* from (select pt2.*, min(case when status = 'Recieved' then txn_date end) over (partition by product) as min_recieved_date    from ( select pt.* from (select pt.*, max(case when status = 'Ship' then txn_date end) over (partition by product) as max_shipped_date from ProductTransaction pt where pt.Product in('P504','P510') ) pt where status = 'Recieved' and txn_date > max_shipped_date )pt2)pt2  where txn_date=pt2.min_recieved_date`